# php with fcgid not working anymore after upgrade to wheezy

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian-wheezy, mod-fcgid

I have some issues with a server that I have recently upgraded from *Debian Squeeze* to *Debian Wheezy*.

When I call a php-page only the php-source-code of the page is beeing show but not interpretated as script.

The php is configured as *fcgid*:

```
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            SuexecUserGroup my-client my-client
            FcgidIOTimeout 240
            <Directory /var/www/my-client.de/www/>
                    Options +ExecCGI
                    AllowOverride All
                    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
                    FCGIWrapper /var/www/my-client.de/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter .php
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
    </IfModule>
```

I am aware if [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/575215/apache2-mod-fcgid-php-stopped-working-after-upgrade-from-debian-squeeze-to-w) post, but the solution doesn't work for me. I tried to rename `FCGIWrapper` to `FcgidWrapper` which didn't help. Beside I have another server running *Wheezy* with `FCGIWrapper` absolutely fine. So I doubt this solution.

Running `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` gives me this result:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 mpm_worker_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 fastcgi_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 jk_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_html_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

The entry `fcgid_module (shared)` tells me that the *fcgid-module* should be loaded and thus fullfill the condition `<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>` from the hostfile.

Futhermore I have checked file `/var/www/my-client.de/php-fcgi-scripts/php-fcgi-starter`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC=/var/www/my-client.de/php
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
exec /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php
```

The directory `/var/www/my-client.de/php` and the binary `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php` are both accessible.

`grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "extension="` gives me:

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini:extension=pdo_mysql.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini:extension=mysqli.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini:extension=gd.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini:extension=mcrypt.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini:extension=mysql.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini:extension=pdo.so
/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini:extension=curl.so
```

`dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i fcgi` gives me:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-fcgid                 1:2.3.6-1.2+deb7u1               i386         an alternative module compat with mod_fastcgi
```

`dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i php` gives me:

```
ii  dh-make-php                          0.3.0                            all          Creates Debian source packages for PHP PEAR and PECL extensions
ii  php-pear                             5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 all          PEAR - PHP Extension and Application Repository
ii  php5-cgi                             5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                             5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                          5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                            5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dev                             5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         Files for PHP5 module development
ii  php5-gd                              5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         GD module for php5
ii  php5-mcrypt                          5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         MCrypt module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                           5.4.4-14+deb7u14                 i386         MySQL module for php5
```

So I am out of ideas how to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated very much!

Answer (score 3):

The issue was caused by `php5_cgi`.

To resolve this issue, deactivate `php5_cgi`:

```
a2dismod php5_cgi
```

More information can be found [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=687307) and [here](https://www.chromosphere.co.uk/2013/12/16/debian-wheezy-apachefcgiphp-changes-to-etcmime-types-and-php5-cgi/).

Comment: thank you, this was really helpful especially the links.